# MongoDb replica set in a single image fails in GitLab CI/CD due to ReplicaSetGhost

Tags: mongodb, docker, .net-core, gitlab-ci, mongodb-replica-set

I am struggling with MongoDb 6 Replica Set and automated testing in CI/CD.

I have created a single docker image with a Replica Set for development and testing purposes.

This works well when running the docker container locally and running my tests against it. See the repository https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs
And see the docker image in the public repository registry.gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs

Basically it has a dockerfile

```
FROM mongo:6.0.5-jammy as base

COPY ./init-mongodbs.sh ./init-replica.sh ./entry-point.sh /

RUN chmod +x /init-mongodbs.sh && \
    chmod +x /init-replica.sh && \
    chmod +x /entry-point.sh

# Data directory
ARG DB1_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/mongo1
ARG DB2_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/mongo2
ARG DB3_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/mongo3

# Log directory
ARG DB1_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mongodb1
ARG DB2_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mongodb2
ARG DB3_LOG_DIR=/var/log/mongodb3

# DB Ports
ARG DB1_PORT=27017
ARG DB1_PORT=27018
ARG DB1_PORT=27019

RUN mkdir -p ${DB1_DATA_DIR} && \
    mkdir -p ${DB1_LOG_DIR} && \
    mkdir -p ${DB2_DATA_DIR} && \
    mkdir -p ${DB2_LOG_DIR} && \
    mkdir -p ${DB3_DATA_DIR} && \
    mkdir -p ${DB3_LOG_DIR} && \
    chown `whoami` ${DB1_DATA_DIR} && \
    chown `whoami` ${DB1_LOG_DIR} && \
    chown `whoami` ${DB2_DATA_DIR} && \
    chown `whoami` ${DB2_LOG_DIR} && \
    chown `whoami` ${DB3_DATA_DIR} && \
    chown `whoami` ${DB3_LOG_DIR}

EXPOSE ${DB1_PORT}
EXPOSE ${DB2_PORT}
EXPOSE ${DB3_PORT}

ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "entry-point.sh" ]
```

and it copies some scripts that run when executing the container

The `entry-point.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/bash ./init-replica.sh &
/bin/bash ./init-mongodbs.sh
```

The `init-mongodbs.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Data directory
DB1_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/mongo1"
DB2_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/mongo2"
DB3_DATA_DIR="/var/lib/mongo3"

# Log directory
DB1_LOG_DIR="/var/log/mongodb1"
DB2_LOG_DIR="/var/log/mongodb2"
DB3_LOG_DIR="/var/log/mongodb3"

REPLICA_SET="${REPLICA_SET_NAME:-rs0}"


mongod --dbpath ${DB1_DATA_DIR} --logpath ${DB1_LOG_DIR}/mongod.log --fork --port 27017 --bind_ip_all --replSet $REPLICA_SET
mongod --dbpath ${DB2_DATA_DIR} --logpath ${DB2_LOG_DIR}/mongod.log --fork --port 27018 --bind_ip_all --replSet $REPLICA_SET
mongod --dbpath ${DB3_DATA_DIR} --logpath ${DB3_LOG_DIR}/mongod.log --port 27019 --bind_ip_all --replSet $REPLICA_SET
```

And the `init-replica.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

DB1_PORT=27017
DB2_PORT=27018
DB3_PORT=27019

LOCAL_HOST="${HOST:-localhost}"
REPLICA_SET="${REPLICA_SET_NAME:-rs0}"
SLEEP_INITIATE="${DELAY_INITIATE:-30}"

RS_MEMBER_1="{ \"_id\": 0, \"host\": \"${LOCAL_HOST}:${DB1_PORT}\", \"priority\": 2 }"
RS_MEMBER_2="{ \"_id\": 1, \"host\": \"${LOCAL_HOST}:${DB2_PORT}\", \"priority\": 0 }"
RS_MEMBER_3="{ \"_id\": 2, \"host\": \"${LOCAL_HOST}:${DB3_PORT}\", \"priority\": 0 }"

echo "Waiting ${SLEEP_INITIATE} seconds before initiating replica set"
sleep ${SLEEP_INITIATE} 
mongosh --eval "rs.initiate({ \"_id\": \"${REPLICA_SET}\", \"members\": [${RS_MEMBER_1}, ${RS_MEMBER_2}, ${RS_MEMBER_3}] });"

echo "Replica set initiated"
echo "$(mongosh --eval "rs.status()")"
```

so that it can be run as

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongors:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs
    container_name: mongors
    environment:
      HOST: mongors
      DELAY_INITIATE: 40
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
      - 27018:27018
      - 27019:27019
```

Notice it accepts an environment variable `HOST` which I can use to give an alias `mongors` so that in GitLab CI/CD I can refer to that hostname.

My app connection string could be something like this

```
mongodb://mongors:27017,mongors:27018,mongors:27019/?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=primary&ssl=false
```

As I said, this works well when running the replica set as a docker container locally (see the docker compose).

**When it runs in GitLab CI/CD it timesout.**
I use shared runners from GitLab.com, the built-in.

> Running with gitlab-runner 16.1.0~beta.5.gf131a6a2 (f131a6a2)

Yet the connectivity seem to work fine

```
$ nc -zv mongors 27017
Connection to mongors (172.17.0.4) 27017 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
$ nc -zv mongors 27018
Connection to mongors (172.17.0.4) 27018 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
$ nc -zv mongors 27019
Connection to mongors (172.17.0.4) 27019 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

So connectivity is OK but I get exceptions from my app like this

```
System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Connected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongors:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongors:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Connected", ServerVersion: 6.0.0, TopologyVersion: { "processId" : ObjectId("646f9b54fb0fbb72cb9a3b70"), "counter" : NumberLong(0) }, Type: "ReplicaSetGhost", WireVersionRange: "[0, 17]", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2023-05-25T17:36:03.9519134Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2023-05-25T17:36:03.9519144Z" }] }.
```

Suggesting that there is a `ReplicaSetGhost` or something wrong with the replica set.

Any idea why in GitLab CI/CD I cannot have my automated integration tests connect to the connection string using the service alias which matches my `HOST` env variable?

At some point I saw in traces this

```
MongoServerError: No host described in new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set rs0 maps to this node
```

So maybe the replica set internally does not understand the hostname `mongors`?

---

**UPDATE 1 (25 May):**
I created a sample repo with a sample pipeline that uses the standalone mongoDB single instance and also the image mongo-rs I created, to test connectivity.

https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs-tester

```
image: ubuntu:22.04

stages:
  - test

test_mongors:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: registry.gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs
      alias: mongors
  variables:
    # MongoDB
    HOST: "mongors"
    DELAY_INITIATE: "50"
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y curl
    - apt-get install -y gnupg
    - curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb.asc > /dev/null
    - echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y mongodb-mongosh
    - sleep 30
  script: |
    output=$(mongosh --host mongors:27017 --eval "db.stats()" 2>&1); if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "OK"; else echo "ERROR: $output"; fi

test_mongo:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: mongo:6.0.5-jammy
      alias: mongostandalone
  variables:
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: dummy

  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y curl
    - apt-get install -y gnupg
    - curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb.asc > /dev/null
    - echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y mongodb-mongosh
  script: |
    output=$(mongosh --host mongostandalone:27017 --username root --password dummy --eval "db.stats()" 2>&1); if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "OK"; else echo "ERROR: $output"; fi
```

---

**UPDATE 2 (29 May):**
Adding the IP to the /etc/hosts didn't make any difference.

```
image: ubuntu:22.04

stages:
  - test

test_mongors:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: registry.gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs
      alias: mongors
  variables:
    # MongoDB
    HOST: "mongors"
    DELAY_INITIATE: "50"
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y curl
    - apt-get install -y gnupg
    - apt-get install -y dnsutils
    - MONGORS_ALIAS="mongors"
    - MONGORS_IP_ADDRESS=$(getent hosts $MONGORS_ALIAS | awk '{ print $1 }')
    - echo "$MONGORS_IP_ADDRESS  $MONGORS_ALIAS" >> /etc/hosts
    - echo "MongoDB IP $MONGORS_IP_ADDRESS added"
    - cat /etc/hosts
    - curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb.asc > /dev/null
    - echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y mongodb-mongosh
    - sleep 30
  script: |
    output=$(mongosh --host mongors:27017 --eval "db.stats()" 2>&1); if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "OK"; else echo "ERROR: $output"; fi

test_mongo:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: mongo:6.0.5-jammy
      alias: mongostandalone
  variables:
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
    MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: dummy

  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y curl
    - apt-get install -y gnupg
    - curl -fsSL https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-6.0.asc | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mongodb.asc > /dev/null
    - echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/6.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-6.0.list
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y mongodb-mongosh
  script: |
    output=$(mongosh --host mongostandalone:27017 --username root --password dummy --eval "db.stats()" 2>&1); if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "OK"; else echo "ERROR: $output"; fi
```

---

**UPDATE 3: 30 May**

To simplify things, I've created this other repository to test my MongoDB Replica Set image

https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs-tester-dotnet

Basically it's a tiny .NET app with an automated test that can run with a

```
dotnet test
```

I have added a `docker-compose.yml` just with a container for my replica set MongoDB image

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongors:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs
    container_name: mongors
    environment:
      HOST: mongors
      DELAY_INITIATE: 40
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
      - 27018:27018
      - 27019:27019
```

and the equivalent for `.gitlab-ci.yml` which **FAILS** (and I don't know why)

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: registry.gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs
      alias: mongors
  variables:
    HOST: "mongors"
    DELAY_INITIATE: "40"
  before_script:
    - sleep 30
  script: 
    - dotnet test
  allow_failure: false
```

The steps would be:

Requirements

- .NET 7 SDK or runtime
- Docker and docker-compose

#### How to run in local

1. Clone the repo
2. Add to `/etc/hosts` (or in Windows `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) this entry with the alias for localhost

```
127.0.0.1   mongors
```

3. Execute `docker-compose up` to spin up a `mongors` container
4. Run tests with `dotnet test`

Verify that the test is successful and it connects to the Mongo Replica Set database

Notice the connection string is `mongodb://mongors:27017,mongors:27018,mongors:27019/?replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=primary&ssl=false`, which uses the alias mongors.

#### How to run in GitLab CI/CD

Now let's try the equivalent in GitLab CI/CD

1. Run the CI/CD pipeline, which will spin up a container service with the alias `mongors` and which will run the dotnet test command as a script
2. Verify that the test is successful if it properly connects to the Mongo Replica Set database.

If the test is unsuccessful and the pipeline fails, it's because the Mongo RS container and tests behave differently when running within GitLab CI/CD. **Why?**

It fails with

```
 System.TimeoutException : A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Connected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongors:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongors:27017", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Connected", ServerVersion: 6.0.0, TopologyVersion: { "processId" : ObjectId("6475c89d5538f6657eda5c74"), "counter" : NumberLong(0) }, Type: "ReplicaSetGhost", WireVersionRange: "[0, 17]", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2023-05-30T09:59:11.3576006Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2023-05-30T09:59:11.3576012Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongors:27018" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongors:27018", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Connected", ServerVersion: 6.0.0, TopologyVersion: { "processId" : ObjectId("6475c89ea07e16061b09e4ec"), "counter" : NumberLong(0) }, Type: "ReplicaSetGhost", WireVersionRange: "[0, 17]", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2023-05-30T09:59:11.3575679Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2023-05-30T09:59:11.3576205Z" }, { ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/mongors:27019" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/mongors:27019", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Connected", ServerVersion: 6.0.0, TopologyVersion: { "processId" : ObjectId("6475c89e4cf3656cf898c899"), "counter" : NumberLong(0) }, Type: "ReplicaSetGhost", WireVersionRange: "[0, 17]", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2023-05-30T09:59:11.3496821Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2023-05-30T09:59:11.3496847Z" }] }
```

---

**UPDATE 4: 31 May**

I have disabled shared runners and created and registered my own Linux runner with `docker` type.

With this runner, the tests went successfully.

https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs-tester-dotnet/-/jobs/4385389688

I hoped services and CI/CD were agnostic of the runner..

Is there any explanation on why it wouldn't work with shared runners?

Comment: The behavior you ask about can depend on runner configuration. Which executor are you using and what is the configuration?

Comment: @hakre I'm using the built-in shared runners in GitLab.com
`Running with gitlab-runner 16.1.0~beta.5.gf131a6a2 (f131a6a2)`
as per https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs-tester-dotnet/-/jobs/4372435084

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and a suggestion: Add the clarification to the question, not in comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it works well locally, that should mean the setup itself is fine, but the way GitLab CI/CD handles networking and/or the way MongoDB replica set resolves hostnames is problematic.

The error message `MongoServerError: No host described in new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set rs0 maps to this node` suggests that the hostname `mongors` is not recognized inside the MongoDB replica set.

By default, MongoDB replica set members communicate with each other using the hostnames that were specified [during the `rs.initiate()` command](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/rs.initiate/). This is typically not a problem when you are running MongoDB instances on separate machines or on a single machine using localhost, but it can cause issues when you are running MongoDB inside Docker containers, where the hostname inside the container may not be the same as the hostname outside the container.

In your case, you are initializing the MongoDB replica set using the HOST environment variable (which is set to `mongors`), so the MongoDB nodes should be using the `mongors` alias for internode communication. However, the error messages you're seeing suggest that the `mongors` alias is not recognized inside the MongoDB nodes.

When you initiate a MongoDB replica set, the hostnames (or aliases) you use are stored in MongoDB's replica set configuration. MongoDB uses these hostnames (or aliases) for internode communication within the replica set.

If you use an alias such as `mongors`, and this alias is correctly [defined in the `/etc/hosts` file](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/) inside the Docker container (which should be the case if you are using [the `alias` feature in GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/services/#accessing-the-services)), then MongoDB should be able to use this alias for internode communication.

(Note: Alias support for the Kubernetes executor [was introduced in GitLab Runner 12.8](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2229), and is only available for Kubernetes version 1.7 or later.)

However, it is important to note that this depends on the alias being correctly defined inside the Docker container, and on MongoDB being able to resolve this alias to an IP address. If there is any issue with the alias resolution, this could cause the problems you are seeing.

Also, if your MongoDB nodes are running in separate Docker containers (as is often the case in a replica set), you will need to ensure that the alias is defined in the `/etc/hosts` file of each container, and that each container can resolve this alias to the correct IP address. If you are using Docker's default bridge network, this should happen automatically. But if you are using a custom network, you might need to add the alias manually using Docker's `--add-host` option.

---

Looking at your [`.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs-tester/-/blob/0378d14d293c6f55a76d7ec1559db8b31ded8762/.gitlab-ci.yml):

In GitLab CI/CD, jobs within the same stage are executed in parallel, but jobs in different stages are executed sequentially.

In your pipeline, both jobs test_mongo and test_mongors are in the same stage, named `test`. So, by default, they would be executed in parallel.

But once `test_mongo` has run, its mongodb standalone instance would be no more.

Each job in a GitLab CI/CD pipeline runs in its own isolated environment. This means that the services defined in a job, like a MongoDB instance in your case, only exist while the job is running. Once the job completes, its environment, including any services that were started, is torn down.

So in your pipeline, the MongoDB instance started in the `test_mongo` job will not exist anymore when the `test_mongors` job starts.
If the `test_mongors` job needs to interact with the MongoDB instance from the `test_mongo` job, it won't be able to because that instance will have been shut down.

I tried and add the necessary sleeps for test_mongors to test access while test_mongo is still running, but [it fails](https://gitlab.com/vonc/mongo-rs-tester/-/jobs/4368549421).

---

Using your second [gitlab-ci.yml](https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs-tester-dotnet/-/blob/d71723ce27fee27512d13adb9a28d2569c08a3f9/.gitlab-ci.yml), I tried [adding a `mongosh --host $HOST --port 27017 --eval "db.stats()"`](https://gitlab.com/vonc/mongo-rs-tester-dotnet/-/blob/134e6f17d71e17ba8447e40752f394c45ebc4381/.gitlab-ci.yml#L15-29).
I got:

```
Accessing MongoDB instance at port 27017
Current Mongosh Log ID: 6476008e02ae6412b3aafec3
Connecting to:      mongodb://mongors:27017/?directConnection=true&appName=mongosh+1.9.1
Using MongoDB:      6.0.5
Using Mongosh:      1.9.1
For mongosh info see: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongodb-shell/
To help improve our products, anonymous usage data is collected and sent to MongoDB periodically (https://www.mongodb.com/legal/privacy-policy).
You can opt-out by running the disableTelemetry() command.
------
   The server generated these startup warnings when booting
   2023-05-30T13:54:57.976+00:00: Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted
   2023-05-30T13:54:57.976+00:00: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended
   2023-05-30T13:54:57.976+00:00: vm.max_map_count is too low
------
MongoServerError: node is not in primary or recovering state
```

At this stage, I would update the Docker image in order to enable the HTTP interface: you would need to start MongoDB with the `--httpinterface` option or `net.http.enabled: true` option in a configuration file.
To enable the RESTful interface, you would need to start MongoDB with the `--rest` option or [`net.http.RESTInterfaceEnabled: true` option](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v2.6/reference/configuration-options/#net.http.RESTInterfaceEnabled) in a configuration file.

You would then be able to use curl or wget to make HTTP requests to MongoDB.

```
curl http://mongors:28017/serverStatus
```

I would check over 120 seconds how that status evolves (every 10 seconds) to try and understand the database cluster status.

---

From the comments:

It works when executed using a GitLab runner "on `sasw-linux`". But it was failing when executed with a GitLab Runner "on `green-1.shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default`.

- using a group GitLab runner that has a docker executor with a default docker image of dotnet core SDK will work
- using a "`shared.runners-manager.gitlab.com/default`" will fail

There was some issue recently with shared runner, like [# 30944: unix socket errors when `NETWORK_PER_BUILD` is enabled on the Shared Runners](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/30944). While it might not be related to the issue at hand, it illustrates a lack of stability on that particular [type of runner](https://repository.prace-ri.eu/git/help/ci/runners/runners_scope.md).

Using one's own runner manually registered seems safer.

Comment: > Here is how you might modify the init-replica.sh script
The file you've provided is identical to the original. Not sure if you meant to add some changes.

I added the IP to the /etc/hosts/ at runtime but it seems there is no difference either.

see pipeline
https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs-tester/-/jobs/4367715698

Comment: @diegosasw OK. I tried and play with the pipeline, but I don't think a job can access a resource of another job like you try to do. I have updated the answer with what I understand.

Comment: thanks for your time. There is no need to run both tests. See my last UPDATE 3 with a different way to test it and a README to test locally and test GitLab CI/CD (where it fails with, apparently, the very same configuration)

Comment: @diegosasw I have edited the answer to report another error I have seen after modifying your second project.

Comment: I don't need that http interface after my Update 3, do I?. I can test database connectivity with the tiny .NET app as described here https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs-tester-dotnet 
As expected, when running those tests locally (and my custom mongo-rs as docker container out of a docker-compose) it connects well. When running those tests in GitLab CI/CD it times out due to `ReplicaSetGhost`. Notice the connection string includes the 3 nodes, not just the first, and uses `mongors` alias also.

Also, I've clarified on my question that I'm using shared gitlab.com runner.

Comment: @diegosasw My issue is that I am not able to test database connectivity with the tiny .NET app, as it fails. So I tried a `mongosh` command, which at least gives a slightly more elaborate error message: `MongoServerError: node is not in primary or recovering state`. Hence, my request for a status of that cluster.

Comment: @diegosasw In [my job logs](https://gitlab.com/vonc/mongo-rs-tester-dotnet/-/jobs/4375015610, I do not see the `Waiting ${SLEEP_INITIATE} seconds before initiating replica set` that I should from the [`init-replica.sh`](https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs/-/blob/8914ac0e412ce1adb23043d8645311573cca7229/init-replica.sh)

Comment: Yes, I see. However when running `docker run registry.gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs` you'll be able to see that. Not sure why is that or whether GitLab CI/CD hides traces within services. Do you think it has something to do with the type of GitLab runner?

Comment: I've created a custom gitlab-runner in my local, and registered it in GitLab.com. I chose Linux option and Docker. My test was now successful. See Update 4
https://gitlab.com/sunnyatticsoftware/sandbox/mongo-rs-tester-dotnet/-/jobs/4385389688

Comment: @diegosasw OK, I have edited the answer to illustrates the difference in types of runner.

Comment: Thanks. I tried enabling shared runners again and specifying tags linux and docker in my .gitlab-ci.yml but, surprisingly, it didn't work. I was looking for a way to use shared runners and have my CI/CD pipelines succeed, as this is a shared project that shouldn't require custom runners available.

Comment: @diegosasw Strange indeed. There seems to be some issues with shared runners.